# MPI_FILE_READ_AT ignores file (don't read the file)

Tags: io, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new at MPI and parallel computing.I wrote simple MPI program in Fortran. But the problem is the `MPI_FILE_READ_AT` ignores and does not read the file.

My code is:

```
  program O72
  use mpi
  !implicit none
  INTEGER :: NINTS, DATATYPE, STATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), mpierr, FH, i
  integer :: taskid, no_tasks, FILESIZE, FILENO_2
  INTEGER(KIND=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: OFFSET
  INTEGER :: BUF(10)
  character :: filename='ab.dat'

  FILESIZE=10
  BUF(:)=0

  call MPI_INIT(mpierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,no_tasks,mpierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,taskid,mpierr)

  NINTS = FILESIZE/no_tasks  !*INTSIZE)
  OFFSET= taskid*NINTS  !*INTSIZE

  call MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "ab.dat", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, &
                     MPI_INFO_NULL, FH, mpierr)
  call MPI_FILE_READ_AT(FH, OFFSET, BUF, NINTS, MPI_INT, STATUS, mpierr)

  write(6,*) taskid, no_tasks
  call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)
  write(6,*) 'taskid=',taskid,'NINTS=', NINTS
  write(6,*) 'taskid_',taskid,'OFFSET=',OFFSET

  write(6,*) BUF(:)

  !call MPI_FILE_WRITE(FILENO_2, OFFSET, BUF, NINTS, DATATYPE, STATUS, mpierr)

  call MPI_FILE_CLOSE(FH, mpierr)
  !call MPI_FILE_CLOSE(FILENO_2)

  call MPI_FINALIZE(mpierr)

  end
```

Then, the input file is an ASCII file with 2 columns in which 1st column is always 1 and 2nd column is always 2.

```
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
1      2
```

And the output comes like this with 2 processor used:

```
0           2
1           2
taskid=           1 NINTS=           5
taskid_           1 OFFSET=                    5
taskid=           0 NINTS=           5
taskid_           0 OFFSET=                    0
171051313   171051313   171051313   171051313   171051313           0           0           0           0           0
822751753   822751753   822751753   822751753   822751753           0           0           0           0           0
```

I don't understand where the problem is and why random values are assigned to `BUF(:)`

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simple answer is that MPI-IO only performs **binary** IOs, while what you try to achieve here is **formatted** IOs.

So starting from here, you see that you have a few problems in your code:

1. You file is formatted. Since as I said in preamble, MPI-IO only performs binary IO, you'll have to, either switch to a binary input file, or to read the file as a set of strings which you'll have to make sense of internally. Let's assume for the rest of this post that your input file is now binary.
2. The `offset` to use in `MPI_File_read_at()` is expected in bytes. What you pass is a number of elements. You therefore need to multiply this offset by the size of what you want to read, aka the size of an `integer`.
3. Finally, you print the full of `buf` which is an array of 10 `integer` whereas you only read `nints` of them. You probably should only print `buf(1:nints)`.

With that, your code should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)